# Google AppEngine local development ImportError

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to setup a flask application that will be deployed on Google App Engine.

My flask application has a dependency on Google Cloud Storage - Datastore.
`google-cloud`, among others.

I ran `pip install -t lib -r requirements.txt` to install all of my dependencies into `lib` directory.

When I run `dev_appserver.py` in root directory of my flask application, I get the following `ImportError`

`ImportError: No module named google.cloud.datastore`

Not sure why I see this. Looking at `lib` directory, it looks like pip installed all my dependencies.

Why isn't local app engine able to find that module.

I realize I should be using App Engine's Datastore, which is slightly different, and requires lot of code changes. But why doesn't App Engine find, and use, Google datastore module

FYI, I am running this on Mac OS-X

Comment: In your `appengine_config.py` file did you specify the path to your `lib` folder?

Comment: Yes, I have that file and added lib to the path.

Comment: Are you still running into the issue? If so - can yo provide the contents of your `dev_appserver.py` & the file structure of your app?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a file named `appengine_config.py` in the same folder as your `app.yaml` file, and add the following lines:

```
# appengine_config.py
from google.appengine.ext import vendor

# Add any libraries install in the "lib" folder.
vendor.add('lib')
```

Read more [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27).